# verify if binary is compiled using gnx gcc or qnx qcc

Tags: gcc, bazel, toolchain, qnx, qcc

I have written a toolchain for qnx gcc and qnx qcc.
I have compiled a sample program using toolchain

```
String dump of section '.comment':
  [     0]  GCC: (GNU) 8.3.0 20190222 (lookup) [qnx710 1535#57]
```

I only see GCC in .comment section when I run above command for both gcc and qcc.
Is this correct ?

Appreciate help?

I would like to verify if this is correct?